# Which dragon books has Tyrion read?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons

We know from *A Game of Thrones* that Tyrion is a voracious reader, and has had a particular interest in dragons since childhood. Given these interests, what books about dragons has the series confirmed that Tyrion has read?

Comment: _How to Train Your Dragon_?

Comment: @SQB That's Daenerys's

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In *A Dance with Dragons* we have Tyrion compiling a book on dragon lore and he mentions reading the following texts:

- A fragment of ***Dragons, Wyrms, and Wyverns: Their Unnatural History*** by Septon Barth.
- ***The Dance of the Dragons, A True Telling*** by Grand Maester Munkun.
- He also mentions Maester Thomax, so he has probably also read Thomax's ***Dragonkin, Being a History of House Targaryen from Exile to Apotheosis, with a Consideration of the Life and Death of Dragons***. The same book is housed in Castle Black and is consulted by Samwell Tarly.
- In the first book, Tyrion borrows an ***unnamed book*** on dragons from the Winterfell library.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:**

- At least one unnamed book from Winterfell.
- "The Dance of the Dragons, A True Telling" by Maester Munkun.
- A note by Ser Byron's squire to his daughter with a correction for the above.
- Some unnamed books lent to him by Illyrio.
- Some other unnamed books and tales that he read sometime in his past.
- Parts of "Dragons, Wyrms, and Wyverns: Their Unnatural History" by Septon Barth.
- Probably read  "Dragonkin, Being a History of House Targaryen from Exile to Apotheosis, with a Consideration of the Life and Death of Dragons" by Maester Thomax.

---

The first book Tyrion reads is in A Game of Thrones but it is an unnamed volume from the Winterfell library that Eddard Stark has let him borrow.

> On the eighteenth night of their journey, the wine was a rare sweet amber from the Summer Isles that he had brought all the way north from Casterly Rock, and **the book a rumination on the history and properties of dragons. With Lord Eddard Stark's permission, Tyrion had borrowed a few rare volumes from the Winterfell library and packed them for the ride north.**
>   He found a comfortable spot just beyond the noise of the camp, beside a swift-running stream with waters clear and cold as ice. A grotesquely ancient oak provided shelter from the biting wind. Tyrion curled up in his fur with his back against the trunk, took a sip of the wine, and **began to read about the properties of dragonbone.** Dragonbone is black because of its high iron content, the book told him. It is strong as steel, yet lighter and far more flexible, and of course utterly impervious to fire. Dragonbone bows are greatly prized by the Dothraki, and small wonder. An archer so armed can outrange any wooden bow.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Tyrion II</sub>

> The boy absorbed that all in silence. He had the Stark face if not the name: long, solemn, guarded, a face that gave nothing away. Whoever his mother had been, she had left little of herself in her son. "What are you reading about?" he asked.
>   **"Dragons,"** Tyrion told him.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Tyrion II</sub>

He also mentions he has read "The Dance of the Dragons, A True Telling" by Maester Munkun and also a note by Ser Byron's squire so he must have read a collection of personal accounts too.

> Tyrion grinned. "Ser Byron Swann. He was roasted for his trouble … only the dragon was Syrax, not Vhagar."
>   "I fear that you're mistaken. **In The Dance of the Dragons, A True Telling, Maester Munkun** writes—"
>   "—that it was Vhagar. Grand Maester Munkun errs. **Ser Byron's squire saw his master die, and wrote his daughter of the manner of it. His account says** it was Syrax, Rhaenyra's she-dragon, which makes more sense than Munken's version. Swann was the son of a marcher lord, and Storm's End was for Aegon. Vhagar was ridden by Prince Aemond, Aegon's brother. Why should Swann want to slay her?"
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Tyrion III</sub>

Later on he mentions he's read some books lent to him by Illyrio and some other accounts of dragons that he dismisses. He states he wishes he could read "The Fires of the Freehold, Galendro's history of Valyria" but does not know of a complete copy. It appears he wants to read "Dragons, Wyrms, and Wyverns: Their Unnatural History" by Septon Barth and "The Death of Dragons". Though it does state he's read parts of "Unnatural History".

> Tyrion had read much and more of dragons through the years. The greater part of those accounts were **idle tales and could not be relied on, and the books that Illyrio had provided them** were not the ones he might have wished for. What he really wanted was the complete text of **The Fires of the Freehold, Galendro's history of Valyria.** No complete copy was known to Westeros, however; even the Citadel's lacked twenty-seven scrolls. They must have a library in Old Volantis, surely. I may find a better copy there, if I can find a way inside the Black Walls to the city's heart.
>   He was less hopeful concerning **Septon Barth's Dragons, Wyrms, and Wyverns: Their Unnatural History.** Barth had been a blacksmith's son who rose to be King's Hand during the reign of Jaehaerys the Conciliator. His enemies always claimed he was more sorcerer than septon. Baelor the Blessed had ordered all Barth's writings destroyed when he came to the Iron Throne. **Ten years ago, Tyrion had read a fragment of Unnatural History that had eluded the Blessed Baelor**, but he doubted that any of Barth's work had found its way across the narrow sea. And of course there was even less chance of his coming on the fragmentary, anonymous, blood-soaked **tome sometimes called Blood and Fire and sometimes The Death of Dragons**, the only surviving copy of which was supposedly hidden away in a locked vault beneath the Citadel.
>   When the Halfmaester appeared on deck, yawning, the dwarf was writing down what he recalled concerning the mating habits of dragons, **on which subject Barth, Munkun, and Thomax held markedly divergent views.** Haldon stalked to the stern to piss down at the sun where it shimmered on the water, breaking apart with every puff of wind. "We should reach the junction with the Noyne by evening, Yollo," the Halfmaester called out.
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Tyrion IV</sub>

Note that he mentions Thomax so it's likely he's read the same tome that Samwell drops and partially ruins, "Dragonkin, Being a History of House Targaryen from Exile to Apotheosis, with a Consideration of the Life and Death of Dragons" by Maester Thomax.

> He had to get down on his knees to gather up the books he'd dropped. I should not have brought so many, he told himself as he brushed the dirt off Colloquo Votar's Jade Compendium, a thick volume of tales and legends from the east that Maester Aemon had commanded him to find. The book appeared undamaged. **Maester Thomax's Dragonkin, Being a History of House Targaryen from Exile to Apotheosis, with a Consideration of the Life and Death of Dragons had not been so fortunate.** It had come open as it fell, and a few pages had gotten muddy, including one with a rather nice picture of Balerion the Black Dread done in colored inks.
>   <sub>A Feast for Crows, Samwell I</sub>

He also later refers to the fragment of "Unnatural History" that he had read earlier.

> If anyone had thought to ask him, Tyrion could have told them not to bother. Unless one of those long iron scorpion bolts chanced to find an eye, the queen's pet monster was not like to be brought down by such toys. Dragons are not so easy to kill as that. Tickle him with these and you'll only make him angry.
>   The eyes were where a dragon was most vulnerable. The eyes, and the brain behind them. Not the underbelly, as certain old tales would have it. The scales there were just as tough as those along a dragon's back and flanks. And not down the gullet either. That was madness. These would-be dragonslayers might as well try to quench a fire with a spear thrust. **"Death comes out of the dragon's mouth," Septon Barth had written in his Unnatural History, "but death does not go in that way."**
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Tyrion XI</sub>